# What is the fastest way to tell whether a table is actually a group table?

Tags: group-theory

[image]

For instance, if I am given a table as above, what is the best way to test whether it is a group?

Apparently, I need to verify it is associative, that is really a good amount of work, and I need to get an answer within one minute.

Comment: You could just observe that this is the table of the cyclic group of order $4$.

Comment: In your specific example, it is easier to just notice that the group is cyclic. However, in the general case you might want to take a look at [Light's associativity test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light%27s_associativity_test)

Comment: In general, you need way more than a minute because the table can be arbitrarily big. It is very easy to check that each row and column is a permutation of the group elements. If this check fails, it fails quickly.

Comment: Are there easier ways generally in $4 \times 4$ situation?

Comment: There are finitely many (read: $2$) groups of order 4, memorizing their tables and checking if this is a permutation of one of them would be fast. It's either cyclic or the Klein 4 group, or it's not a group.

Comment: You need to get an answer in one minute? With arbitrarly large table? I'd say write a program that will do all checkings for you. Then you just have to make sure you can pass the table to it in 1min. :) Otherwise, the test is bullshit.